SwiftUI - Combine Multiple Text Views
I am new to SwiftUI and trying to understand how I can combine multiple text views that can end up being a different view type because of setting the background color, as an example. Below is my current code and what I am currently achieving. This works, however using HStack it doesn't display the text left to right correctly.
I would rather just combine all the text views if possible but could not figure out how to do that since some text views end up as "any View". I have also tried modifiers but it never seems to apply the background color.
Thanks!
private func getTexts() -> some View {
    HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 5) {
        let words = note.text.components(separatedBy: " ")
        ForEach(words.indices, id: \.self) { index in
            let currentWord = words[index]
            if (currentWord.lowercased() == "Reading".lowercased()) {
                Text(currentWord)
                    .padding(.all, 4)
                    .background(.yellow)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8, style: .continuous))
            }
            else {
                Text(currentWord)
            }
        }
    }
}

When outputting just one line on the screen with the code above I get the result shown below:

I want to achieve the picture above but with multi-line text:


Without the padding and rounded corners, this can be done with an AttributedString. If you absolutely need those, this becomes very difficult. I'd suggest wrapping a UITextView and do some TextKit with it. See this question and the questions linked by it.

Might worth looking at this.

Google flow layout

@Carsten Thanks! This is definitely the closest answer to what I was looking for and provided helpful context.

I am also experiencing a similar challenge as you. I found an article that talks about a potential solution using AttributedString.
struct ContentView: View {
    var message1: AttributedString {
        var result = AttributedString("Hello")
        result.font = .largeTitle
        result.foregroundColor = .white
        result.backgroundColor = .red
        return result
    }

    var message2: AttributedString {
        var result = AttributedString("World!")
        result.font = .largeTitle
        result.foregroundColor = .white
        result.backgroundColor = .blue
        return result
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text(message1 + message2)
    }
}

